# Why Typescript return type void in interface doesn't trigger error in implementation?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying two different classes in Typescript playground that implement the same interface. I can't figure out why a method `speak()` with `void` return type in the interface doesn't trigger an error if it's implementation returns something other than void.

I have to explicitly implement the method with a return type `void` to trigger the type-checking. This doesn't seem to happen for return types other than `void`, as shown below.

[Snippet in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMshgA4RwDWAFAJQBcyAblsACYDcxpA7nAA2dJshABXALYAjaDyIBfYsQgAPclihhkCQXAwZkACSlwQAeRApgk8oIiSI4Q+ijZchEmUo0G+XqTIUBBg4lC4AORGEIKCWBFcyAD0ScgAcljIYACelMjQUJoBSl4Cwn54gVWBKcgAKrkoBUVepMGh4cgRAOpC1KAA5gnFxCUq6prauvqGJpJmdXyZNnYOTmAumDj+XhRUIsxsnDtV7WGR0bHxibUNec1QI6V9DMwSMtAngWedPX2DCWSqTuTSghUeXhKCiAA)

```
interface Person {
  speak(): void;
  walk(): number;
}

export class HumanOne implements Person {
  speak() {
    return 'Hello';   // No type error
  }
  walk() {
    return 'Walking'; // Type error
  }
}

export class HumanTwo implements Person {
  speak(): void {
    return 'Hello';   // Type error
  }
  walk(): number {
    return 'Walking'; // Type error
  }
}
```

Comment: `void` means that the type of the function's return will not be used (and the type will be ignored), see the guide on [callback types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#callback-types)

Comment: "Contextual typing with a return type of void does not force functions to not return something." See [this doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void) for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inferred type of the method without the explicit type declaration is `HumanOne.speak(): string`. This is compatible with `void`, which has two meanings:

- in a function implementation with return type `void`, it means that it doesn't return anything, more or less equivalent to specifying `undefined` as a return type.
- in a function type declaration, `void` means that *anything* can be returned, and that the return value of calls must not be used. It's more or less equivalent to `unknown` as far as type compatibility is concerned (but unlike `unknown`, you can't really pass around values of type `void`).

This second meaning is also what is relevant for the subtype checking of `HumanOne implements Person` - the type `() => string` is a subtype (or: assignable to) type `() => void`. If you call `Person.speak()`, you must ignore the return value (and it might be `undefined`, a string, or anything else); if you call `HumanOne.speak()` you'll know that you get a string back.

This is very much by design, see [the docs on *Return type
void*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void) and the [FAQ entry "*Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?*"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void).

Comment: If I want to ensure the callback function being passed to my function has no return value and is a true `void` function, how would I accomplish that, if type `() => void` works similarly to `unknown`?

Comment: Then you'll declare your callback to be `() => undefined`. But I don't see a reason to do that.